# Getting Swift_header compilation error for tvOS

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, tvos, apple-tv

I have a tvOS project contains an App target and 3 static libraries:

EntryPoint – Static library that contains main , AppDelegate and SceneDelegate

Experience – Static library containing my UI elements

AppTarget – executable built using above two libraries

I have a class "SelectionTable" which subclasses UITableView in Experience target :

```js
import UIKit

 class SelectionTable : UITableView
{
    private var vDataSrc:[String]!

    func SetDataSrc (_ pDataSrc:[String])
    {
        self.vDataSrc = pDataSrc
    }

    func UpdateDataSrc (_ pStringList:[String])
    {
        self.vDataSrc += pStringList
    }

    func GetDataSrc () -> [String]
    {
        return self.vDataSrc
    }
}
```

I am not using this class anywhere and still i am getting these errors when i build my AppTarget:

> Cannot find interface declaration for 'UITableView', superclass of 'SelectionTable'

> Expected a type

These above error are coming in generated header file "Experience-Swift.h". This file is auto-generated by compiler. I am not using @objc anywhere in the code, But still the Target-Swift.h file has the below lines:

```js
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC10Experience22SelectionTable")
@interface SelectionTable : UITableView
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder * _Nonnull)coder OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

When i am marking above class as Private , this error goes away .

And also , if i am defining SelectionTable class in EntryPoint library , this error does not occur .

I am using similar model for an iOS project also and there i am not facing this issue.

I am using :- Swift version : Swift 5.9.2 XCode version : 15.2